# Encontrar o driver jdbc mysql e estabelecer conexão

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer uma conexão com o java diretamente com o jdbc. Eu inseri no projeto o jar do mysql jdbc em propriedades do projeto, javabuildpath e adicionando o jar externo. Estou fazendo o seguinte exemplo e me parece que não encontra o banco.

```
import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.SQLException;  

public class Disciplina {  

private int idDisciplina;  
private String disciplina;  
private float cargaHoraria;  

public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {  
Connection conexao = DriverManager  
.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ucsal");  
System.out.println("Conectado!");  
conexao.close();  
}  
}
```

Obs: lança excessão, não tratrei porque eu quero ver o erro. E sobre o jar inserido, quando eu vou em javabuildpatch, na aba library, o mysql jdbc não tem nada dentro da biblioteca. Tudo está none (source target "none", java doc location "none", native library location "none").

Eu só baixei o jar, não baixei o restante do conteúdo da pasta mysql_jdbc.zip.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eu fiz a classe de conexão da seguinte forma:

```
package conect_DB;  

import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.SQLException;  

public class Conexao {  

    public static java.sql.Connection conexao;    
    private static String servidor = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ucsal";    

    public static boolean conectar() {    
    try {    

        Class driverMysql = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");    

        conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(servidor, "root", "");    

        if (conexao == null) {    

        return false;  
        }  
    }  

    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {    
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " on method 'conectar' error");    
    }    

    catch (SQLException e) {    
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());    
    }    

    return true;    
    }    

    public static void desconectar() {    
    try {    
        conexao.close();    
    }    

    catch (SQLException e) {    
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());    
    }    

    catch (NullPointerException e) {    
        System.out.println("method 'close()' error. Not conection opened");    
    }    
    }    

}
```

Comment: Esta é a solução da sua pergunta?

Answer (score 2):

**1º-** Verifique em seu **servidor de banco de dados**, se você realmente criou a base de dados `ucsal`;

**2º-** Falta adicionar o login e a senha de acesso ao seu **servidor de bando de dados**, neste caso ficaria assim:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ucsal", "seuLogin", "suaSenha");
```

**3º-** acredito que vc não tenha adicionado o ***driver*** de maneira incorreta. Uma maneira de fazer isso é:

1. criando uma pasta em seu projeto, intitulada **`lib`**;
2. copie e cole o do seu ***connectorJ*** neste diretório;
3. depois adicione-o ao seu ***classPath***, caso você esteja usando o **Eclipse**, botão direito no **Driver** > **build Path** > **Add to Build Path**.

Comment: Ok, funcionou. Agora já estou fazendo as query's. Gratro.

Comment: @AndréNascimento, blz. Agora é só marcar como resposta da pergunta. :)